# How to do AssociationThread recursively?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, mapthread

Consider the following sequence of deepening lists:

```
s = {s1, s2};
t = {{t1, t2}, {t3, t4, t5}};
c = {{{c1, c2, c3}, {c4}}, {{c5}, {c6, c7}, {c8, c9}}};
i = {{{{i2},{i1,i3},{i1}},{{i1,i4,i5}}},{{{i1,i2}},{{i6},{i4,i7}},{{i4,i8,i9},{i1,i3,i5,i9}}}};
...
```

What is the easiest way to write a function `GeneralizedAssociationThread` to achieve generally the following for an arbitrary sequence of deepening lists:

```
GeneralizedAssociationThread[s,t,c,...]
```

producing

```
<|s1 -> <|t1 -> {c1, c2, c3}, t2 -> {c4}|>, s2 -> <|t3 -> {c5}, t4 -> {c6, c7}, t5 -> {c8, c9}|>|>
```

---

Even deeper example:

```
GeneralizedAssociationThread[s,t,c,i,...]
```

producing

```
<|s1 -> <|t1 -> <|c1 -> {i2}, c2 -> {i1, i3}, c3 -> {i1}|>, t2 -> <|c4 -> {i1, i4, i5}|>|>, s2 -> <|t3 -> <|c5 -> {i1, i2}|>, t4 -> <|c6 -> {i6}, c7 -> {i4, i7}|>, t5 -> <|c8 -> {i4, i8, i9}, c9 -> {i1, i3, i5, i9}|>|>|>
```

Answer (score 3):

This feels a bit jenky, but maybe it'll get you started toward something cleaner:

```
AssociationThreadRecursively[list_List, lists__List] :=
  Merge[AssociationThreadRecursively @@@ Transpose[{list, lists}], First];
AssociationThreadRecursively[key_, list_List, lists__List] := 
  <|key -> AssociationThreadRecursively[list, lists]|>;
AssociationThreadRecursively[key_, value_] := <|key -> value|>
```

Demonstration:

```
AssociationThreadRecursively[s, t, c]
(* <|s1 -> <|t1 -> {c1, c2, c3}, t2 -> {c4}|>, s2 -> <|t3 -> {c5}, t4 -> {c6, c7}, t5 -> {c8, c9}|>|> *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html).

```
foldToAssoc[hiearchy : Repeated[_List, {2, ∞}]] :=
 Association@
  Fold[
   Association[
       If[Equal @@ Map[Length, #]
        , MapThread[Rule, #]
        , Rule@@#
        ]
       ] & /@ Transpose[Reverse@{##}] &
   , Reverse@{hiearchy}]
```

With `s`, `t`, `c` as in OP.

```
foldToAssoc[s, t, c]
```

> ```
> <|s1 -> <|t1 -> {c1, c2, c3}, t2 -> {c4}|>, 
>   s2 -> <|t3 -> {c5}, t4 -> {c6, c7}, t5 -> {c8, c9}|>|>
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: With, say `r = {{{r1, r2, r4}, {r4}}, {{r5}, {r6, r7}, {r8, r9}}}`, `foldToAssoc[s, t, c,r]` gives error.

Comment: That `r` does not have `AtomQ` keys in `c`.  This gives a flat association from `foldToAssoc[c, r]` which then as incorrect dimensions for level `t`. The pattern provided in the OP example is `AtomQ` keys for the children below.

Comment: @kglr I have added another deeper list in my question for you guys to test your code against.